# QTextEdit: how to make blocks of read-only text with custom metadata?

Tags: python, pyqt, rich-text-editor

I am developing a rich text editor for documents that must support simple "placeholder" macros, generating some program-defined text. Think of "Field" feature in MS Word:

[image]

A macros must be represented in the editable document as a pierce of read-only text, that user can cut/copy/paste, but can not edit. It must store some technical information.

The ideal solution would be to have a read-only span of text, that flows with the rest of the document and allows special interaction via context menu. Acceptable solution would be to have a single element (like display:inline-block in css) with custom text.

Is it possible at all, and if it is, then what would be the right technique to implement such feature?

Comment: Without any research, from the top of my head, subclass QTextEdit and make it switch to read-only when cursor enters this kind of block, or when current selection contains even a part of one. Should be easy to detect when cursor moves or selection changes, and perform the check. Also don't forget drag&drop, you probably have to check those separately. Also if this is really critical, add some extra checks to go through all these text blocks eg. when saving, in case user finds a novel way to change them anyway.

Comment: @hyde in order to distinguish such fragment from the regular text, I have to associate some user data with them. What is the correct way to do it? Should I put it to QTextCharFormat?